# How to automatically attach instances to AWS EC2 load balancer and route traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

In the EC2 panel I can attach EC2 Linux machines by instance id or by IP address. I want sometimes to provision new EC2s manually, and I want them included in Load Balancer. I don't like load balancer configuration because instance names are confusing. Is there a way to create an elastic IP or a network card which will I be attaching to a new instance and this network card or elastic IP will be registered in load balancer and used to route traffic to multi-instances? I know that elastic IP is alone and LB won't be able to choose how to balance, but I hope you can understand what I mean here - I'm trying to simplify set-up, maybe you can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use elastic IPs on this kind of instances as you'll run out rather quickly. Remember there's a (soft) limit of 5 per region.

About adding the instance to your load balancer, what you can do is register them into the target group upon launch. Adding something like `aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn YOUR_TG_ARN --targets "[ { 'Id': 'THIS_INSTACES_ID' } ]"` into your User Data after you obtain the instance's id.